# Run same thread in loop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want to run the thread below multiple times and everytime it finished print the result to tkinter's Label.

```
    def hasher(path):

        hashed_file = self.hash256(path)
        tk.Label(self, text=hashed_file).pack()

    t = []
    for directory in files_dict:

        for file in files_dict[directory]:

            t.append(threading.Thread(target=hasher, args=(directory+"/"+file,)))

    for thr in t:
        thr.start()
        thr.join()
```

Basically to be able to later update a label with "Finished proccessing : "
However if I add .join() it freezes and if I remove it will finish and then load the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the last for-loop you are starting a thread `thr` from list `t` with `thr.start()` and then waiting for it, preventing other threads from the list `t` to be started in the first place. You need need an extra loop for the `thr.join()` statement:

`for thr in t:
    thr.start()`


`for thr in t:
    thr.join()`